# SASS compilation error [expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was ...]

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, node-sass

I was using node v0.12, and just wanted to update my npm packages, however, the new version of node uses node-sass and libsass as a compiler.

I am using grunt-sass to compile my files, but ended up with a lot of errors that occur only with Libsass.

Here is an example that seems happen on sassmeister.com when using the Libsass compiler.

The solution is to add a space after the :, fine, but this is not the solution am seeking, any help please?

Here is a gist to experiment the issue and it has a weird fix tho.

http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b8197cf0593d722f808809e8979f2ab9

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a problem with sass or a problem with integrating `node-sass`? You probably mean that your project needs a more recent version of `node-sass` (which uses `libsass`) after upgrading Node.js. This one in itself doesn't use node-sass. Please clarify.

Comment: If you don't put the space after de `:` the compiler expects a pseudo-class or pseudo-element because it supposes you write a selector not a CSS property

Comment: You also get an error when you switch to Sass 3.3 in the menu. This is only compiles at all in 3.4 or 4, which seem to be more error tollerant.

Comment: Well, @E_net4, if you are using an old version of node, lets say 0.12.*, it wont install Libsass when you are using the corresponding grunt-sass version of that particular node version, and such an issue wont happen because it uses Ruby to compile SASS which is slower than Libsass and node-sass, however, when I switched to node v4 and updated my npms, it starts throwing errors such the one I am showing.

Try to write the code in the picture using the same website, and use the Sass compiler not "Libsass" and it will work just fine.

Comment: Exactly @nschonni, it seems that the new version of the compiler is more sensitive to such syntax, However, there is also another error regarding using extend inside media, for example:
`@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  @extend %whatever;
}`

Its not cool to do such a thing, but the code we are using is somehow old and its huge, thats why I was looking for an automated solution for these errors however.

Comment: @blonfu, That true buddy, thats why I want a different solution that checking my X files and change that to have a space tho.